# Moshi Custom Adapter for generic List<T:Enum> returns List<List<T:Enum>> instead of List<T:Enum>

Tags: generics, kotlin, moshi

(Also opened an issue here: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/768 but was asked to open also a stackoverflow question)
I am writing a generic adapter to convert a json-string with lists of enum values. The standard-adapter for enums throws an exception when the list contains an enum-value that is not available. I want to create an adapter that simply skips unknown enum values instead of throwing an exception. I succeeded partially, but for some reason, the object that was converted was not a `List<Enum>` but instead a `List<List<Enum>>`.

This is the adapter that I came up with:

```
package com.mytestcompany.appname.utils

import com.squareup.moshi.*
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

class SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapter<T : Enum<T>>(enumType: KClass<T>) : JsonAdapter<List<T>>(){
    val jsonNameToEnum = HashMap<String,T>()
    val enumToJsonName = HashMap<T,String>()

    init{
        val enumConstants =  enumType.java.enumConstants
        for(enumConstant in enumConstants){
            val constantName = enumConstant.name
            val jsonName = enumType.java.getField(constantName).getAnnotation(Json::class.java)

            val lookupName = jsonName?.name ?: constantName
            jsonNameToEnum[lookupName] = enumConstant
            enumToJsonName[enumConstant] = lookupName
        }
    }

    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(jsonReader: JsonReader): List<T>{
        val list = ArrayList<T>()
        while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
            val jsonNameValue = jsonReader.nextString()
            val entry = jsonNameToEnum[jsonNameValue]
            if(entry!= null){
                list.add(entry)
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, list: List<T>?){
        if(list!=null){
            for(item in list){
                val jsonName = enumToJsonName[item]
                if(jsonName != null){
                    writer.value(jsonName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the unit test code:

```
package com.mytestcompany.appname.utils

import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner


data class TestJsonClass(
    val testJsonSubClass: TestJsonSubClass
)

data class TestJsonSubClass(
    val tags: List<Tags>
)

enum class Tags {
    @Json(name="tag1") TAG_1,
    @Json(name="tag2") TAG_2,
    @Json(name="tag3") TAG_3,
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapterTest {

    lateinit var jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<TestJsonClass>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(Tags::class.java, SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapter(Tags::class))
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
        jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(TestJsonClass::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun moshiAdapterKnownEnumsTest() {
        val json = """
            {
                "testJsonSubClass": {
                    "tags": [
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2",
                        "tag3"
                    ]
                },
                "validation": {}
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val testJsonClass = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)
        Assert.assertTrue(testJsonClass?.testJsonSubClass?.tags?.count() == 3)
    }

    @Test
    fun moshiAdapterUnknownEnumsTest() {
        val json = """
            {
                "testJsonSubClass": {
                    "tags": [
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2",
                        "tag5"
                    ]
                },
                "validation": {}
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val testJsonClass = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)
        Assert.assertTrue(testJsonClass?.testJsonSubClass?.tags?.count() == 2)
    }
}
```

When debugging the testJsonClass object of the second test, i can see the following values (similar for the first test as well):
[image]

I think this is related with the CollectionJsonAdapter, because the custom adapter is called via the CollectionJsonAdapter. Before I thought i would get the collection passed to the converter and wrote the `jsonReader.beginArray()` and `reader.endArray()`, but that was already done for me:

```
   //in CollectionJsonAdapter.java 
  @Override public C fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    C result = newCollection();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      result.add(elementAdapter.fromJson(reader));    // calls the custom adapter
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return result;
  }
```

I am not sure what I can do to solve this issue, I cannot return individual values in my adapter so it needs to be a list, but I also don't know how to force moshi to not use the CollectionJsonAdapter and pass the whole collection to my adapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register your adapter as handling `List<Tags>`, not `Tags`.

```
.add(Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Tags::class.java),
    SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapter(Tags::class))
```

Also, you need to add jsonReader.beingArray() and jsonReader.endArray() calls in your decoding implementation. (Note that you don't need `@FromJson` for directly extending `JsonAdapter`.)

```
override fun fromJson(jsonReader: JsonReader): List<T> {
  val list = ArrayList<T>()
  jsonReader.beginArray()
  while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
    val jsonNameValue = jsonReader.nextString()
    val entry = jsonNameToEnum[jsonNameValue]
    if(entry!= null){
      list.add(entry)
    }
  }
  jsonReader.endArray()
  return list
}
```

Bonus: You can optimize SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapter with JsonReader.Options.

```
class SkipNotFoundEnumInEnumListAdapter<T : Enum<T>>(enumType: Class<T>) : JsonAdapter<List<T>>() {
  private val nameStrings: Array<String>
  private val constants: Array<T>
  private val options: JsonReader.Options

  init {
    try {
      constants = enumType.enumConstants
      nameStrings = Array(constants.size) {
        val constant = constants[it]
        val annotation = enumType.getField(constant.name).getAnnotation(Json::class.java)
        annotation?.name ?: constant.name
      }
      options = JsonReader.Options.of(*nameStrings)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
      throw AssertionError("Missing field in " + enumType.name, e)
    }

  }

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<T> {
    reader.beginArray()
    val list = mutableListOf<T>()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      val index = reader.selectString(options)
      if (index != -1) {
        list += constants[index]
      } else {
        reader.skipValue()
      }
    }
    reader.endArray()
    return list
  }

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: List<T>?) {
    if (value == null) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("Wrap in .nullSafe()")
    }
    writer.beginArray()
    for (i in value.indices) {
      writer.value(nameStrings[value[i].ordinal])
    }
    writer.endArray()
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, registering the adapter was the problem. I previously had the `beginArray()` and `endArray()` calls in the code but noticed that beginArray() was already called (because of the wrong registration).

Comment: is there an alternative way to write the code above but avoid using the spread operator?

Comment: @eric-cochran I wonder if this should not be the default behavior for Moshi for all List<Enum>, or at least allow this to be set through some flag on Moshi Builder, instead of using an adapter.

I've created an issue on Github to discuss this:
https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1118